# Why does top offset, when given in % doesn't move the relatively positioned element vertically?

Tags: html, css, css-position, viewport-units

Let's say there's a relatively positioned div element. When I set the top value in %, it does nothing at all. But as soon as I express it in px, it works. Is there any particular reason/logic?

This doesn't work

```
<style>
div{
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  top:20%;
}
</style>

<body>
<div>Hello</div>
</body>
```

While this works

```
<style>
div{
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  top:20px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div>Hello</div>
</body>
```

I tried putting this div inside a container and it worked. And the amount it moved was realtive to the height of the containing element.

Comment: It's an interesting question. According to the CSS specifications, percentage top and bottom of containers without a defined height _should_ work. Unlike height, margins and padding, the height of the containing block does not depend on the top and bottom values - i.e. there is no circular dependency - so there's no technical limitation why it can't work. It seems that it doesn't because web-compatibility and browser interoperability mean the browsers' behaviour can't be changed. IMO, the CSS positioning specification needs updating.

Comment: @Alohci Note that here `position: relative;`

Comment: @imhvost - yes indeed. My point is that vertical percentages could (and spec-compliantly, would) work for `position:relative`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you need to set `height` to parent element, or `min-height` + `display: grid`:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```